# Taking user input to define the value of a variable in the private section C++

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm creating a hash table in C++ and am a bit rusty in my C++.
I'm able to code everything fine when pre-defining the size of the hash table, however, I want the user to be able to determine how large they want the hash table to be.

Currently in my Hash.h file, in the private section, I have the following piece of code..

```
    // static const int tableSize = 10;
    static const int tableSize = 100;

    //Types of things that the item consists of

    struct item {

        string name;

        string drink;

        item* next; //Point to next item in the hash table
    };

    item* HashTable[tableSize];

};
```

My goal is to have that tableSize variable be an integer that is typed in by the user. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<item *>`.

Comment: If you use a `std::list` or `std::vector`, you can drop the `next` pointer, as the order is basically handled by the position in the list or vector.

Comment: Is it not possible to have the user enter in some variable integer value and assign it to the table size they want to use? This is the way it's supposed to be made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a const vector of items with a mutable list.

The const vector should be initialized with its size, and it won't let you add more entries, the mutable list will let you add items to it.

Here you can see a sample:

```
struct item{

};

struct items{
    mutable list<item> entry;
};

int main() 
{ 
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    const vector<items> hashtable(n); 

    /*
      hashtable.push_back(...) is illegal.
      You can't add elements to it, since it is const, 
      so the initialized size will be fixed.

      BUT: list is changeable since it mutable, 
      so the following is legal:
     */
    int i = 0
    item t;
    hashtable[i].entry.push_back(t);
```

Comment: So if I were to do it as I have already programmed, is it possible to do something like int tSize; Then call cin >> tSize. Some variation of that?

Comment: All you can do is use dynamic allocation, since a global array can't be reallocate in c++,

Comment: So there is no way to have a user define the size of the array? I need to use an array, not a vector.

Comment: So then create a dynamic array.. Make the hash-table a dynamic array.

Comment: `item** HashTable= new item*[tableSize];`